# Limit Realm results

Tags: android, realm

How do I limit the amount of objects Realm returns? .findAll returns all rows matching the query and .findFirst returns only the first. But what about something like first 1000? .findAll may return so many rows that it consumes way too much memory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The cool thing is that you don't need to worry about that with Realm. The result object returned from a query is lazily loading the objects and its fields when you access them. Your objects are never copied and thus only represented once in memory/disk.

The (current) implementation detail of this is that the RealmResults object returned from a query is just a list of references to the matching objects. Those references are tiny numbers which are stored compressed so they take up very little memory. So even with 100.000 matches it actually wouldn't take up much memory. And it would take up the same amount of memory for all kind of objects, whether they have one int field or hundreds of fields with strings or big binaries.

Comment: what if is store the realm result using copyFromRealm method to List<> ?

Comment: Then you would copy out all the objects and they would take up the full amount of memory that your normal Java objects does. So that's a really bad idea if you have many results. You always want to avoid copying our Realm objects unless you have to e.g. send then over the network.

Comment: Is there any way to remove specific column when we store into realmResult. Because I have a large amount of data in one column but I display some small size values in recyclerview from the realm result pojo.

Comment: No there isn't. But as explained in the answer realmResult does not itself copy the data, it only hold an index  to the "row" of the object in the underlying data, so the memory realmResult uses is independant of how much data and how many columns you have.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to achieve this after so many days using "between" query as found in the official docs https://realm.io/docs/java/latest

If you want to fetch first N elements, Simply pass the count from and to with field name as below

```
realm.where(clazz).between("count",0,1000).findAll();
```

Where,

**"count"** = Field name (i.e variable name in your pojo) 
 **"0"** = Range From 
 **"1000"** = Range to

For example: The above query will fetch first 0 to 1000 as RealmResults.

Note: The above solution works only if you have some unique id with row count. In my case I manually inserted row count value before inserting the values into Realm.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be this, if you really want only `RealmResults`, using [Stream](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) `limit` method:

```
//get all results of your choice query
RealmResults<TypeClass> entities = realm.where(TypeClass.class).findAll();
//limit using Stream
List<Integer> ids = Stream.of(entities).limit(10).map(x -> x.Id).collect(Collectors.toList());
//return only those ids elments
return realm.where(TypeClass.class).in("Id", ids.toArray(new Integer[])).findAll();
```

Comment: Don't forget to recalculate these in `entities``s RealmChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

Realm currently do not provide any limit function but if you want first N elements

```
int N=10;   // whatever value you want
Realm mRealm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();

RealmResults<Example> list= mRealm.where(Example.class).findAll();
list.subList(0,N);
```

for last N elements

```
RealmResults<Example> list= mRealm.where(Example.class).findAll();
list.subList(list.size()-N,list.size());
```