# Android Realm find first N element

Tags: android, database, sqlite, realm

How I can select first N element from Realm database. 
Now,I use this code to select N elements:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
.where(MyObject.class)
.findAllSorted("myField", Sort.DESCENDING)
```

But this select operation is too long. I need to SQL 'LIMIT' operation analog.

Comment: One solution is in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39689393/2002079

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at this
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/544

seems realm results are lazy loaded so you dun need "limit" when using realm

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
int N=10;   // whatever value you want
Realm mRealm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();

RealmResults<Example> list= mRealm.where(Example.class).findAll();
list.subList(0,N);
```

Comment: list.sublist will return List collection which will not work as RealmResult.

Comment: yes List<Example> will be returned ....if you want ReamResults  then sorry there is no direct solution for that by realm in Android

Answer (score 2):

**I did that using limit method,** **You should use latest version**         `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"`

```
RealmResults<YourPOJOClass> realmResults = mRealm.where(YourPOJOClass.class).sort("createdTime").limit(10).findAll();
//here this record will be sorted by ascending order using schema name "createdTime" 
//this will return the 10 rows only.
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate Since I already posted the solution here : [Limit Realm results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852573/limit-realm-results/46563580#46563580)

I figured out the solution to achieve this after so many days using "between" query as found in the official docs https://realm.io/docs/java/latest

If you want to fetch first N elements, Simply pass the count from and to with field name as below

```
realm.where(clazz).between("count",0,1000).findAll();
```

Where,

**"count"** = Field name (i.e variable name in your pojo) 
 **"0"** = Range From 
 **"1000"** = Range to

For example: The above query will fetch first 0 to 1000 as RealmResults.

Note: The above solution works only if you have some unique id with row count. In my case I manually inserted count value before inserting the values into Realm.