# Realm limit query results

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm new to Realm, and I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29875237/6356671) about limiting realm queries (in a lot of other places too).

My problem is that the following code is taking too long to load the data into the array when the amount of data gets big:

```
RLMResults* rlm = [[Item class] objectsWithPredicate:predicate]; // this loads fast
NSArray* results = [rlm valueForKey:@"self"]; // this is slow
```

as far as I know I can't limit the results using the predicate too, so I am trying to limit the results like [this example](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#limiting-results) in the realm website, as follows:

```
RLMResults* rlm = [[Item class] objectsWithPredicate:predicate]; // this loads fast
NSMutableArray* results = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Item* item = rlm[i]; // only the first call (when i == 0) is slow here
    [results addObject:item];
}
```

so the interesting thing here is that only the first call of rlm[i] (rlm[0]) is taking long, and afterwards (when i > 0) the call works fast.

Am I doing something wrong? or is there any way to load big amount of data faster or to limit the results?

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like it says in the Realm documentation, the contents of `RLMResults` are lazy-loaded. It's built to try and defer 'pre-loading' anything until it is absolutely necessary. When you loop through each object it and add it to an `NSArray`, that's forcing each object to get lazily-loaded, which will (understandably) result in a performance hit. It's also probably that the bulk of the predicate query is being executed lazily as well, which is why you get the performance hit when you access the first object in the results set, and not when you're creating the `RLMResults` object.

If you consider this performance hit from doing this is unacceptable, you might want to consider trying a different approach to this. For example, instead of copying the objects to an `NSArray`, use the `RLMResults` object, and keep track of only the objects you want using an `NSRange` object. Additionally, since only the initial load is slow, I would also suggest you try and optimise your predicate query as well, for example, making sure each property you're searching against has been marked as indexed.

If worse comes to worse, sometimes long performance hits can't be helped, and if that's the case, you can mitigate any UI freezing by offloading it to a background thread.

I hope that helped!

Comment: Thank's for the reply, I don't think using RLMResults would work (didn't find any example using it either), and if Realm really has no other way to Limit the results (yet?), optimising the predicate query (not always possible) AND making it load in a background thread was the only way for me to make it faster and not freeze the UI.

Comment: You're welcome! There's a few examples and explanations of `RLMResults` on the Realm documentation page (Especially under queries: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#queries) as well as the sample code. Adding a limiting features has been discussed in the past (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2608) but it was decided there's no real reason to add a hard mechanism like that since it doesn't make sense with Realm's lazy loading implementation (It's just a matter of *not* looping through each object returned in `RLMResults`. :) ). Cool! Good luck!

Comment: So there's not really a possible limit, I'll mark this as an answer then ;)

Comment: So just to clarify... there's no need to paginate because the lazy loading is efficient enough?

Comment: That’s correct! Realm only lazy loads the properties you end up accessing, and past accessed ones are autoreleased over time. So there’s usually no need to do any pagination logic for long query results.